# Microsoft PowerBI embedded with password

Tags: authentication, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am working with PowerBI Embedded but I am quite new.

The following is my customer request. They want to have the dashboard embedded in their webpage but before opening they want to have password. They will just get the URL and add as iFrame in their webpage.

I plan to use the Embedded API to make the webpage using the token provided. 
However this will not prompt the user to login.  Is there any way I could do that? Maybe I will have to write the app in as whole to monitor the user authentication.

Comment: Have you explored the securing the webpage / webapp that is housing the embedded dashboard, rather than trying to password-protect the embedded content? It tends to be a poor user experience when landing on a site and being prompted to see some pieces of information but not others.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using 'User owns data' scenario of Power BI Embedded, then each user HAS to be authenticated on his own, and is limited to access only resources in his possession (or that were shared with him).

If you're using 'App owns data', you can control whichever auth process you'd like, and grant access to the embedded entity as you please.

Read about the different approaches:

https://guyinacube.com/2016/07/3-ways-to-embed-power-bi/